# Must all nodes on the blockchain execute every smart contract function cal?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I understand why it's important that all nodes on the Ethereum mainnet must execute any smart contract function call which changes the internal state of the contract or the chain. (For example, transfers from one account to another ec.)

What I'm wondering is, if its true that every node must execute **every** function called on any smart contract, even if the function doesn't result in a state change.

For example, if an ERC721 smart contract has a function "getName()" which just returns the name of the artwork the NFT represents which is stored in the NFt.  Let's say joe connects to the network, and wants executes getName() on a contract.  Does that mean that all 9,000 nodes end up spinning cycles executing getName(), even though Joe only needs it to be executed once?  Does the gas cost of running "getName()" compensate each of the nodes for the overhead of running "getName()"?  If that is true (that every node gets paid) will gas get even more expensive as more nodes join the pool?

Is one of the reasons gas prices are high is because of the inefficiency of every node having to execute every function called on a smart contract, even those that have no effect on state?

If so it would seem to be a very (and perhaps unnecessarily) expensive proposition to execute a computationally intensive but "pure" (no side effects) function on Ethereum, right?

Thanks.  apologies for the possibly naive question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a difference between a [transaction](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sendTransaction) (can make state changes - but doesn't need to), and a [call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) (read-only, cannot make state changes).

---

I'll start with the call simply because it's easier.

When a node performs a call, it executes the contract function that most likely reads from storage, stores to memory, and returns from memory.

Example:

```
string name;

function getName() external view returns (string memory) {
    // reads from storage, stores to memory, returns from memory
    return name;
}
```

But it doesn't broadcast any info (such as "I've just performed a read operation") to other nodes. I.e. other nodes don't perform the same operation.

---

A transaction is executed once on each node.

```
string name;

function setName(string memory _name) external {
    // reads from memory, stores to storage
    name = _name;
}
```

A miner takes a transaction from the mempool (list of transactions waiting to be mined), executes it on their machine, performs the state changes, and add the transaction to the block (including the expected state changes).

All (validator) nodes then download the new block, execute the transactions, and perform the same state changes on their end. If they find a mismatch betweeen their own state changes and the state changes declared by the miner, they broadcast this into the network, declaring a possible invalid block.

---

To answer your questions:

> *Does that mean that all 9,000 nodes end up spinning cycles executing getName(), even though Joe only needs it to be executed once?*

If Joe requests a call, `getName()` is executed only on one node (where Joe is connected to). If he requests a transaction, it's executed on all nodes.

> *Does the gas cost of running "getName()" compensate each of the nodes for the overhead of running "getName()"?*

It only compesates the (winning) miner, who takes the transactions fees. Larger tx fees (the total amount of ETH, not the gas price) compensate for bigger use of resources (mostly CPU time) that the machine needs to use, compared to multiple "easier" transactions that they could execute using the same resources.

> *If that is true (that every node gets paid) will gas get even more expensive as more nodes join the pool?*

Not every node gets paid, see above.

> *Is one of the reasons gas prices are high is because of the inefficiency of every node having to execute every function called on a smart contract, even those that have no effect on state?*

It's probably mostly for economic reasons - supply and demand. The more people want to execute their transaction as fast as possible and are willing to pay higher gas price, the higher they are going to push the gas price. Possibly they just use the price recommended by their wallet app, which can be higher than the average.

Comment: 1/That's extremely helpful Petr, thank you.  A couple of follow ups. 1/ is a node paid for the execution of a call?  what if a smart contract provided a service  which was computationally expensive (say, a fluid dynamics problem) but made no state changes?  If the service function was requested as a call would the single node just have to bear the cost of running that for free.  Could gas be required?).

Comment: 2/    On the other hand, lets say there was a smart contract which provided an answer to a computationally intensive problem for a fee paid by the caller.  Could the function be constructed in some way where the hard work was done by a signle node, but the fee transaction is propagated to all nodes>

Comment: 1) Node is not paid for an execution of a call. At least not in the form of "gas fees" in the native currency of the network (ETH on Ethereum network, BNB on BSC network, etc.) that is usual for transactions. But there might be another forms of payment. E.g. node provider [Infura](https://infura.io/pricing) offers limited free plan and paid plans with higher limits. But the limits apply only to a number of requests so they probably calculate the limits based on some average computational cost.

Comment: 2) I haven't seen this approach on the public networks, and since all nodes are considered equal it's most likely impossible on a public network. It might be possible to set up using a private network (e.g. [Hyperledger Fabric](https://www.hyperledger.org/use/fabric)) with a set of rules defining execution on node A and validation on node B, or no validation at all.

Comment: thanks for your great answer. you said above, If Joe requests a call, getName() is executed only on one node (where Joe is connected to).  is there a possibility that the node is a malicious one and send fake data as response to the getName() call, if so, how to prevent it.

Comment: @TylerXue Yes, a malicious node is a possibility. If you can't trust a single 3rd party node, you can either request the data from multiple nodes to lower the risk of receiving data from a malicious node, or you can [run your own node](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/run-a-node/).